# msrp field doesn't show on product edit form

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

The attribute seems to have come with Magento2 as I cannot delete it.  It is set to global, I made sure the database lists it as is visible, it is set through attribute set, I added another field called product_msrp that does show up and work but why does the msrp field not show up?  I would much rather use this field as it might be tied to other modules/functionality and already have data imported into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The msrp field is part of the MAP pricing system and is only available in advanced pricing if MAP pricing is turned on however it totally changes the pricing behavior of your store with tons of consequences you probably don't want so just making an attribute and pushing it to your design with strikethrough is how you have to go about it.  And I thought this was a global feature even the most basic carts had...  I actually don't know an eCommerce site that doesn't list the retail price next to the actual price except now magento2 out of the box.

Source here: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-Feature-Requests-and/Magento-2-1-fresh-Install-Missing-quot-MSRP-quot-from-Advanced/idi-p/45205

Additionally if you do the "fix" suggested by one person and go to turn on map pricing there's this warning message:

"Warning! Enabling MAP by default will hide all product prices on Storefront."

What a terrible feature...  a store with no prices.  Further, none of this is documented anywhere I can find.